# Unexpected behaviour of a recursive insertion sort function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, typeerror

I was writing a recursive insertion sort function in Python 2.7 and came across two things I can't understand.

The first was the error `TypeError: can only assign an iterable`, which I guessed it had to do with the recursion of the function, but I don't get in particular the problem with my code :

```
def recursiveInsertionSort(v):
    if len(v)!=2:
        v[0:len(v)-1]=recursiveInsertionSort( v[0:len(v)-1])
    i=len(v)-1
    while v[i-1]>v[i]:
        v[i-1], v[i]=v[i], v[i-1]
        i-=1
        if i==0: return v
```

The second problem it's probably connected.

In this case I didn't even get an error (if you know why please tell me) but the function just didn't work.

```
def recursiveInsertionSort(v):
    if len(v)!=2:
        recursiveInsertionSort(v[0:len(v)-1])
    i=len(v)-1
    while v[i-1]>v[i] and i>0:
        v[i-1], v[i]=v[i], v[i-1]
        i-=1
```

As I guessed the problem was with the recursive use of the function I corrected my mistake:

```
def recursiveInsertionSort(v):
    if len(v)!=2:
        temp=v[0:len(v)-1]
        recursiveInsertionSort( temp)
        v[0:len(v)-1]=temp
    i=len(v)-1
    while v[i-1]>v[i] and i>0:
        v[i-1], v[i]=v[i], v[i-1]
        i-=1
```

But I really would like to understand the causes of these two behaviors, can you help me?

EDIT I also ask if there's a nicer way of doing:

```
temp=v[0:len(v)-1]
recursiveInsertionSort( temp)
v[0:len(v)-1]=temp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your first implementation was with the `if` statement inside the loop. If the loop exited because `v[i-1]` was less than or equal to `v[i]`, it would not `return` anything (which in Python is the same as doing `return None`). The `TypeError` you're getting is from the recursive call that gets the `None` value returned to it, since you can't assign `None` to a slice.

You can make the first version of your code work if you combine the two conditions in the `while` statement and return `v` unconditionally after the loop ends:

```
while i > 0 and v[i-1] > v[i]:
    v[i-1], v[i] = v[i], v[i-1]
    i -= 1
return v
```

You probably should put the conditions in this order in your other version too.

As for why your second version didn't work, the issue was that you were slicing the original list, getting a new list with a partial copy of its contents. Then your recursive sort was modifying that copy in place. But then the outer function didn't have any way to see the changes, since it didn't keep a reference to the sliced copy. Your third version fixes this by explicitly saving the slice as a new variable.

I don't think there's any better way to do the exact three lines of your last code block. However, if you changed the function to accept an optional paraemter of the highest index to sort, you could do without slicing at all:

```
def recursiveInsertionSort(v, i=None):
    if i is None:
       i = len(v) - 1
    if i > 1:
        recursiveInsertionSort(v, i-1)
    while v[i-1]>v[i] and i>0:
        v[i-1], v[i]=v[i], v[i-1]
        i-=1
```

This is going to be a little bit more efficient than your current code, as it doesn't copy the list for each recursive call. Both versions are still `O(N**2)` though, so don't expect it to compete with `quicksort` or other more efficient sorts on large data sets.

Comment: I didn't notice that, but it doesn't explain the "Type error". I think that the problem that you exposed didn't come up when I was checking if it was working, because it was having problems with     v[0:len(v)-1]=recursiveInsertionSort( v[0:len(v)-1]), but i dont know why.

Comment: The `TypeError` occurs in the previous recursive call, when it tries to assign `None` to a slice.

Comment: I've edited to explain a bit more about where the exception comes from, and to suggest an improvement to your other implementation.